# Minificação Sass css/js

Tags: javascript, css, sass

Estou procurando um software para windows, que faça a minificação de arquivos js/css em saas, atualmente só conheço codekit, mas é pra mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o **GRUNT** também

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin

Comment: acha que minificando os arquivos js e css eu consigo fazer com que minha página não aparece o código quebrado antes de renderizar, ou existem outros tipos de critérios que tenho que levar em conta?

Comment: olá @MichelHenriq, qual tipo de código quebrado.. experimente carregar o .js de forma assíncrona, se sua aplicação permitir. No arquivo Gruntfile.js é possível unir/minificar dois ou mais arquivos .js ou .css, caso tenha necessidade. Você pode também passar um compress nas imagens, ajuda um pouco na renderização.

Answer (score 0):

Software pago conheço o **Prepross**.

Tem como usar o **gulp.js** que é o processamento interno do CodeKit.

### GULP

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

### Live Reload

http://livereload.com/